# How to use a logic OR in a jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to join two JS that do exactly the same thing but with different jquery selectors:

A:

```
var names = $('span[name|="name"');
for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
        ...
}
```

B:

```
var names = $('span.author a').not('.authlink');
for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
        ...
}
```

As all the code in the for{} is exactly the same, I´ll want to do

```
var names = $("A" OR "B");
for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
        ...
}
```

But can´t make it work

I tried

```
var names = $('span[name|="name",span.author a').not('.authlink');
var names = $('[span[name|="name"],[span.author a]').not('.authlink');
```

and several other combinations but was unable to make it work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: like any css selector ... `,`

Comment: Tried that $('span[name|="name", span.author a').not('.authlink'); but does not work

Comment: perhaps you  missed the `]` .... i.e. `span[name|="name"], span.author a`